# I want to send mail to all the employees who work on that department when a Client adds a ticket

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, codeigniter

I have a ticket system. So I want whenever a user creates a new ticket a mail will be send to all the employees who work on that department.

**Following is my model code:**

```
public function ticket_email() 
{

        $query = $this->db->select('staff_sign_up.email')
                            ->distinct('staff_sign_up.email')
                           ->from('staff_sign_up')
                        ->join('view_ticket','view_ticket.initial_department=staff_sign_up.department_id')
                           ->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

This model is fetching all the mail id of those employees who are working in that department.

**Following is my controller code:**

```
public function ticket_send() {
        $subject = 'A Ticket has been added please check & reply asap';
        $message = '
   <h3 align="center">Ticket Details</h3>
    <table border="1" width="100%" cellpadding="5">
     <tr>
      <td width="30%">Subject</td>
      <td width="70%">' . $this->input->post("subject") . '</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td width="30%">Description</td>
      <td width="70%">' . $this->input->post("description") . '</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
   ';
        $config = Array(
            'protocol' => 'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
            'smtp_port' => 465,
            'smtp_user' => '******@gmail.com',
            'smtp_pass' => '*******',
            'mailtype' => 'html',
            'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
            'wordwrap' => TRUE
        );
        $this->load->library('email');
        $this->email->initialize($config);
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
        $this->email->from('manojit.chakraborty58@gmail.com', 'admin');
        $this->email->to($this->auth_model->ticket_email());
        $this->email->subject($subject);
        $this->email->message($message);
        if ($this->email->send()) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Your ticket has been generated,please wait sometime for reply');
        } else {
            show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
        }
    }
```

So,this is the controller is supposed to send mails to all those employees who work on that department with the ticket details.

I'm having these errors:

> object of stdclass could not be converted into string

and

> preg_match expects parameter 2 to be string but object given

I'm using CodeIgniter 3 and am a beginner.

**Edit after Alex's comment:**

result_array is returning the following item:-

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [email] => *****@gmail.com ) [1] => Array ( [email] => *******@example.com ) [2] => Array ( [email] => *******@gmail.com ) [3] => Array ( [email] => ******@gmail.com ) )
```

**After the latest update by Alex:**

[image: this is the output that's coming]

Comment: Have you checked what the `ticket_email()` returns? It’s not a string.

Comment: hey, remove your email and password from the code.

Comment: And then change your password

Comment: I did print_r & it returns std object class.

Comment: change it to `result_array()` and do the `print_r()` again and then dump that to a pastebin or imgur (you can blank out the emails in paint or something if you aren't using dummy data). we just need to see how its formatted; couple of rows of data will suffice.

Comment: Yes I did. It's showing the following the output:-                                                                            Array ( [0] => Array ( [email] => *****@gmail.com ) [1] => Array ( [email] => *******@example.com ) [2] => Array ( [email] => *******@gmail.com ) [3] => Array ( [email] => ******@gmail.com ) )

Comment: Please take more care with the protection of your client's personal data - there is no excuse whatsoever for posting it here, since you have to do it with intent when you post the image. It is not your data to be careless with. I will see if a Stack Overflow developer can delete the image [from your question history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51394887/revisions).

Answer (score 2):

You can try change the smtp host to ssl://smtp.gmail.com

Comment: If I put an original email then the mail is getting send,So I don't think that will be a problem but I will still try thanks for the input.

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't seem to be getting it in the comments: `$this->auth_model->ticket_email()` according to your scheme returns the result object. You need to get a string (or an array) that looks like:

```
$this->email->to('one@example.com, two@example.com, three@example.com');
```

OR

```
$this->email->to(
            array('one@example.com', 'two@example.com', 'three@example.com')
);
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html#CI_Email::to

So at the very least you should be returning a `result_array()` but chances are you'll have to do some work to convert it into an array CI will accept.

---

Update

```
public function ticket_email() 
{

        $query = $this->db->select('staff_sign_up.email')
                            ->distinct('staff_sign_up.email')
                           ->from('staff_sign_up')
                        ->join('view_ticket','view_ticket.initial_department=staff_sign_up.department_id')
                           ->get();
        if ($query->num_rows() == 0) {
            show_error('whatever');
        }
        return array_column($query->result_array(), 'email'); // make array CI email lib can understand
    }
```

and you can keep everything else the way it is. Although I would advise to check if `num_rows() > 0` and handle circumstances where it isn't accordingly.

Comment: Yes I did. It's showing the following the output:- Array ( [0] => Array ( [email] => *****@gmail.com ) [1] => Array ( [email] => *******@example.com ) [2] => Array ( [email] => *******@gmail.com ) [3] => Array ( [email] => ******@gmail.com ) )

Comment: Hey  @alex I updated my code can you please check what is the issue. Previously I used foreach to send mail but there was a problem that the mail was going to only one employee.

Comment: That's an entirely different issue that I cannot address in the comments but essentially you need to configure the email system for loclhost. There are plenty of information on this elsewhere on stack

Comment: also i'm not sure if you noticed but the clients emails are in the image you posted

Comment: Yes I see all the emails are coming so the model works and code works thanks for that but I'm saying successful when I'm sending mail to one particular person. So, I don't understand why I can't send mail to multiple peoples at the same time.

Comment: No I meant that you might want to blank those out haha. I don't really know why it isn't working for multiple but is working for one tbh.

Comment: It's working under one but not working more than one. I don't know why. @Alex thanks anyway u helped me a lot.

Comment: I upvoted u yestarday since u solved my actual problem and I also blanked out those emails. thank u for everything have a nice day or night.